# Align multiple formats of text onto rows

Tags: html, css

The goal is to get the Kanji, English, and Kana rows of text lined up with each other into a specific format. Such that the text is largely interchangeable and isn't hard-coded.

The Kanji and English should be evenly placed next to each other. The Kana should be aligned with the top of the second row.

It was working before, but it was hard-coded, I commented out those regions.

It should look like this:

[image]

```css
body {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 60%;
 font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
 word-break: break-all;
}

#header {
 padding-top: 10px;
 width:100%;
 height:286px;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
 #kanjiTransl{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 5.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*left: 25px;*/
  /*top:15px;*/
  line-height: 1.1em;
 }
 #jaN {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 #kana {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #777;
  /*position: inline;*/
  /*right: 30px;*/
  /*top:130px;*/
  /*font-size: 1.4em;*/
 }
 .top {
  letter-spacing: -0.07em;
 }
 .bottom {
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  /*margin-left: 12px;*/
 }
 .topColor {
  /*color: #FF2EDF;
  color: #84FF00;
  color: #b4FF00;*/
  color: #a78317;
  color: #908090;
 }
 .bottomColor {
  /*color: #84FF00;
  color: #FF2EDF;
  color: #dc3616;*/
  color: #9f3420;
  color: #222266;
 }
 .headerItem {
  display: inline-block;
  /*height:110px;*/
  /*width:900px;*/
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*left:.6em;*/
  /*line-height: 110px;*/
  font-size:15em; 
  font-weight:900;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
   <div id="kanjiTransl">
    <span id="jaN" class="topColor">驚<br>的<br></span>
    <span id="jaV" class="bottomColor">速<br>記</span>
   </div>
   <span class="headerItem top topColor">LARGE</span><br>
   <span class="headerItem bottom bottomColor">WARNING</span>
   <span id="kana">ノテイショナルヴェロシティ</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what i should like?

Comment: @CodeiSir Uploaded screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Layout and tune it to your needs:

```css
#header {
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 286px;
  width: 850px;
}
#jaN,
#jaV {
  font-size: 5.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #777;
}
#kana {
  float: right;
}
.top,
.bottom {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.top {
  letter-spacing: -0.07em;
  color: #908090;
  font-size: 15em;
  line-height: 0.3em;
}
.bottom {
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  font-size: 10em;
  line-height: 0.3em;
  color: #222266;
}
```

```html
<table id="header">
  <tr>
    <td id="jaN">驚
      <br>的</td>
    <td>
      <span class="top">NATIONAL</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="jaV">速
      <br>記</td>
    <td>
      <span class="bottom">VELOCITY</span>
      <span id="kana">ノテイショナルヴェロシティ</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've still been unable to get the kana aligned with the top of the "velocity"

Comment: set a custom line-height

Comment: I got it now. Thank you